# How to add page content and webform as tab in a page?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm using drupal 7 and I have a content type "service".

And I have a enquiry page, built with webform with following fields:

- Name
- Email
- Service
- Message

In each service page, I would like to have a tab for page content, a tab "Enquiry", with the enquiry webform in the tab.

For service field, I would like it to show page title as default.

Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do that :

1. Write a custom module and create a menu path "node/%node/enquiry" and return your enquiry form programmatically. In hook_menu you can set `type = MENU_LOCAL_TASK` that will display the path as tab.
2. You can create a view page that displays webform and select the menu `Menu tab` under menu setting. Path of page should be `node/%/enquiry`, so that It will create a tab on `node/%` page. Screenshot for the second method :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs)

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content,
>   specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can
>   create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with
>   corresponding content.

[Try out a demonstration](https://www.drupal.org/node/494618)

Comment: But I want to have my page content as first tab, and "Enquiry" as second tab. Quick tabs doesn't allow me to put my page content on tab?

Comment: Yes it will allow you do so.

Comment: In one quick tab, I add webform tab and content tab (with node ID). But this is applicable to one page only? And for another page, I have to add another quick tab instance with different node ID? Or is there a setting for quick tab to automatically show different content in different page?

Comment: Workaround will be adding the `Quick Tabs` as a block and enable it on every page.